# G++ abs() on a short int appears to turn it into a double?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, g++

The following code does not compile if `std::abs(angle)` is present. The type of `angle` is in this case a `short int`.

```
template <class T>
typename T::storage_t::single_t FastSin(const typename T::storage_t::double_t &angle) {
  const int B = (sizeof(typename T::storage_t::single_t)*8) - 2;
  return (angle<<1) - ((angle*(std::abs(angle)))>>B);
}
```

A close look at the messages can verify that `angle` is in fact a `short int`. However, if I am reading the error correctly, GCC turns it into a `double`.

```
math.hpp: In function ‘typename T::storage_t::single_t FastSin(const typename T::storage_t::double_t&) [with T = Fixed<_t<signed char, short int> >, typename T::storage_t::single_t = signed char, typename T::storage_t::double_t = short int]’:
vector.hpp:106:30:   instantiated from ‘void Vector2<T>::FastRotate(const single_t&) [with T = Fixed<_t<signed char, short int> >, Vector2<T>::single_t = signed char]’
test.cpp:9:18:   instantiated from here
math.hpp:11:52: error: invalid operands of types ‘__gnu_cxx::__enable_if<true, double>::__type {aka double}’ and ‘const int’ to binary ‘operator>>’
```

What is going on here? Even `return (angle<<1) - ((angle*(std::abs<int>(angle)))>>B);` does the same.

I am using gcc version 4.6.1. The only external headers included are `<cmath>` and `<cstdint>`. The compilation flags are `-std=c++0x -Wall`.

Comment: What is `T::storage_t::double_t`? If it's double, the parameter `angle` will be a `double` inside the function even if you pass it an integer. If you enable verbose warnings you might get a warning about it.

Comment: If I say that `angle` is a `short int`, and `angle` is a function parameter declared as `T::storage_t::double_t`, then you can certainly deduce that `angle` is an integer. And looking at the error message, you will see that only integers are involved, just to make it clear. The name '`double_t` comes from it being twice the storage size of `single_t`.

Comment: I was confused having a type ending in `double_t` being a short integer.

Comment: Generic debugging hint: If the error message of a compound statement is confusing for you, take it apart. You get much more meaningful messages that way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`abs()` is not a template, but a set of overload functions. According to the standard, the overload for `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `long double` should exist. But the overload for `short` does not exist. But as the conversion sequence from `short` to `int` is only a promotion, and the conversion sequence form `short` to the other overloaded types are all conversions, the overload for `int` should be selected.

But in g++ (version 4.5.2 for me), a non-standard template is added to `cmath`:

```
template<typename _Tp>
inline typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<__is_integer<_Tp>::__value,
    double>::__type
abs(_Tp __x)
{ return __builtin_fabs(__x); }
```

This template would take all built-in integral types other than `int` and `long` and give a return value of `double`.

As a matter of fact, using type `unsigned int` also produces this error in g++:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
int main() {
    unsigned int i,j;
    i=0;
    j=std::abs(i)>>2;
    return 0;
}
```

Explicitly casting it to `int` (`std::abs((int)i);`) should solve this problem.

Comment: Very helpful. I thought my problem was solved when I simply included `<cstdlib>` instead of `<cmath>`, as indicated by another answer. As it turns out, if I include both, the problem reappears, for the reason you outline. Your solution is a bit messy in a template situation such as in my original question. Simply casting a template parameter to an `int` isn't very dynamic. I currently use `__builtin_abs()` directly, which isn't exactly very portable.

Comment: As a consequence of that template function, `std::abs<int>(int)` also returns `double`.  Crazyness.

Answer (score 5):

The `std::abs()` function isn't a template in C++; there are just several overloads provided for different types.  The ones for the integral types are in the header `<cstdlib>`.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/abs/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/abs/ for more info.

Comment: Wow, that is the kind of detail that will slip right by if you aren't careful. Thanks for noticing! (Btw, nothing stops you from simply removing the part of your answer that got my question wrong, no one is interesting in reading that in the future.)

Comment: Will do.  I am new to posting answers on this site, so I wasn't sure what the proper etiquette was.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is already answered long ago, but i just want to give another perspective which should help someone else. My problem was with QT and mingw, always when i build with boost or some other libraries which use cmath and cstdlib i got this error. After some time i was pretty annoyed with this error, and i decided to do a little research about those two files.
I totally agree with fefe and his answer but that can only solve problems if you use it in you program or library ,and you know from a start what is a problem, and that wasn't my problem.

If you really need to include both files in same time (you need system, malloc... and all math functions) quick and dirty fix is to open  header and on 106 line (on my computer) you will see something like this:

```
    namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
    {
    _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

      using ::div_t;
      using ::ldiv_t;

      using ::abort;
      //using ::abs;
      using ::atexit;
      using ::atof;
      using ::atoi;
      using ::atol;
      using ::bsearch;
      using ::calloc;
.
.
.
```

From code above you can see that cstdlib have function abs in std namespace and you need to comment that line in order to enable use of cmath abs function and to get rid of that nasty error.

I hope that this will help someone, and i am sorry for such a long post.